# not able to excute a delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

i'm writing a small tweak for instagram to implement a UIalert when double tapping on the picture to ask whether i want to like the photo or not here is my code so far

```
#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>

%hook IGFeedItemPhotoView

-(void)onDoubleTap:(id)arg1{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention"
                                                    message:@"Are you sure you want to like this pic?"
                                                    delegate:self



                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];

[alert show];
[alert release];
```

}

```
%new(v@:@@)
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Button Index =%ld",(long)buttonIndex);
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        nil;
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        nil;
    }
}
```

instead of nil in buttonIndex ==1 i want to return the orig value of the method but i can't because its a new method (%new) how do i let it return the %orig value ? thanks in advance

Comment: the UIAlert is showing fine but when i press yes or no i get the same result i want the no answer to give me the the %orig

Comment: Use a [BlockAlertView](http://nscookbook.com/2013/04/ios-programming-recipe-22-simplify-uialertview-with-blocks/).

Comment: can you guide me how to use BlockAlertView?

Comment: Did you read the link? What _specifically_ don't you understand?